# How do I find this matrix that represents a transformation with respect to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

How is it possible to find $[T]_E$ if I do not know how the transformation defined? How do I find $[T]_E$ when Given:

let $T$ be linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$B = ((1,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,0,1))$ ordered basis of $\mathbb{R} ^3$.

$[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Multiplying $[T]_B$ by the column vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ will give you the definition of the transformation $T$ for any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @MattDyer What is $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Comment: It is just an arbitrary column vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You are given the matrix of transformation for some $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. What this matrix tells us is the output of the transformation if we simply multiply any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the transformation matrix. So if we just multiply the transformation matrix by some arbitrary vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ we get an explicit description of the transformation $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have that $(x,y,z)=x(1,0,1)+y(0,1,0)+(z-x)(0,0,1)$. Hence the coordinates of $(x,y,z)$ w.r.t. the basis $B$ are $(x,y,z-x)$. Thus $T(x,y,z)=[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z-x
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\ 1&0&-1\\ 0&-1&2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ y \\ z-x
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
-2x+2y+3z\\ 2x-z\\ -2x-y+2z
\end{pmatrix}_B$.

Unless I don't understand the notation $[T]_B$.

Edit : Thus you get the coordinates of $T(x,y,z)$ w.r.t. the basis $B$. Hence $T(x,y,z)= (-2x+2y+3z)(1,0,1)+(2x-z)(0,1,0)+(-2x-y+2z)(0,0,1)$. Thus $$T(x,y,z)=(-2x+2y+3z,2x-z,-4x+y+5z).$$
Thus $$[T]_E=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&2&3\\2&0&-1\\-4&1&5
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Where did you show what $[T]_E$ is?

Comment: Is this equation is true $[T]_B[x]_B = [Tx]_B$? if so, I do not understand why you say that $[T]_B[x]_B = [T]_E$, sorry but probably I miss something..

Comment: I made a silly mistake, I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

What $[T]_B$ gives you is a matrix such that for all vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ we have $[T]_B[x]_B=[Tx]_C$ for some basis $C$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$. We are looking for is a matrix $[T]_E$ such that for all vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$, $[T]_E[x]_E=[Tx]_C$. Now notice that for any $x\in \mathbb{R^3}$ we have $[x]_B=P_{E\to B}[x]_E$ where $P_{E\to B}$ is simply the change of basis matrix. As this matrix remains unchanged for all $x\in \mathbb{R^3}$ we can see that the matrix $[T]_BP_{E\to B}$ will provide the $[T]_E$ that will satisfy our requirements. As you know both bases you should be able to compute $P_{E\to B}$ fairly simply.

Comment: Why you say that $[T]_B[x]_B = [Tx]_C$? I learned that is should be like that $[T]_B[x]_B = [Tx]_B$

Comment: Usually the correct notation is $[T]_B^C[x]_B=[Tx]_C$ to show that that you transform a vector in terms of $B$ under $T$ into a transformed vector in terms of $C$. Often in first linear algebra courses it is assumed that the basis used in the co-domain and domain is the same (for $T:V\to V$) in which case they abbreviate to the notation you're familiar with.